# Creating a get_absolute_url()

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting an `404` error when trying to post. But the error is `event objects don't have get_absolute_url() methods`

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/events/', null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    # I made this, but this doesn't work
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/event/" + self.id

    # it returns : 
            Exception Type:  TypeError
            Exception Value: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

How do I properly make this work? Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: can you post the urls.py file related to that model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a format string.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/event/%d" % self.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` value from `get_absolute_url` is trying to combine a string and number.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/event/{0}".format(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

self.id is a number and you're trying to convert it to number in url...
you can still do "+" operation if you convert it's type to desired string...
so you must do:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/event/" + str(self.id)
```

and it will work. This way you can do Unicode conversions and so on... By specifying exact type you want an output to be.
However other constructions seem to be quicker. But I prefer this one because of visual clarity in what's going on in this piece of code...